# Message Archive Management Plugin (Prosody) can't open archive

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite, xmpp, prosody-im

I'm trying to get Message Archive Management ( mam ) on a prosody server
working.
I tried it with SQLite3, MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Always this log:

```
Oct 20 14:56:21 general info    Hello and welcome to Prosody version 0.9.7
Oct 20 14:56:21 general info    Prosody is using the epoll backend for connecti$
Oct 20 14:56:22 localhost:mam   error   Could not open archive storage
```

The archive is existing in /var/lib/prosody/.

Comment: Are you using https://modules.prosody.im/mod_mam.html? That module only works with Prosody 0.10+.

Comment: I updatet to this version but it's still the same error.

Comment: Could you set your log level to "debug" and then post a log?

Comment: @Nick Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is designed specifically for questions about programming. For help with setting up and configuring Prosody, you may find help more easily through any of the options at: https://prosody.im/discuss